# Is it possible to record sound with HTML5?

Tags: html, html5-audio

I'm considering a web-version of some of our programs and considering HTML5 and Flash.

Anyone know if it's even possible to record audio with HTML5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

umm , it's pretty old news but i am just answering for posterity purposes . Google has proposed a Sound Capture API which is still under consideration under W3C HTML speech incubator group  ( http://www.w3.org/2005/Incubator/htmlspeech/ ). Google also has posted a TTS example which works on Chrome beta 
http://slides.html5rocks.com/#speech-input
all you have to do is

> < input id = "speech-input-field"
>   type="text" x-webkit-speech />

Answer (score 5):

A [device element](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#devices) that would likely make this possible has been proposed.

It is very new and support among browsers will be somewhere between "weak" and "non-existent".

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this feature is available yet, but its been rumored that HTML5 will be able to in the near future.