# Open Source Mic Capturing on a Website

Tags: audio-capture

I'm looking for a solution of capturing a Microphone on a website. 
I would really like it to be open source and/or at least free (if I have to install a special server or what/not) 
Quality of sound is the most important issue here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has already been asked: [Is it possible to record sound with HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996377/is-it-possible-to-record-sound-with-html5)

There is no real HTML/JavaScript solution yet. It can be done with Flash, however. If you want to do that, [here's a good example and tutorial](http://www.kirupa.com/developer/actionscript/microphone.htm).

Comment: My hatred towards flash is so great that I'm going to ask you: is it possible to do it with a Java Applet?

Comment: Most likely, but I have never used Java, so I don't know. A quick Google search couldn't find any examples for me, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

@Asaf well to add to already given flash solutions ,

- Flash
  http://sziebert.net/posts/server-side-stream-recording-updated/ . This solution uses Red5 and flash ( getMicrophone() call http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/main/00001866.html ) .
- Silve Light also has Sound Capturing facility . ref: https://twitter.com/chuckstar/status/10541469193
- Java 
  There is a sample working code in Java which can record sound in Ogg file Fomrat , but i am not sure if it can work on websites http://code.google.com/p/mind-listening/source/browse/trunk/freemind/mind-listening/jorbis-0.0.15.jar?spec=svn37&r=37

Comment: I've tried to play with Red5 a while back, it took a couple of weeks to get it working and even then - the quality was pretty bad.

Comment: yeah red5 has pretty steep learning curve but its way ahead of other projects like [1] Mammoth http://mammothserver.org/ [2]PyAMF http://www.pyamf.org/index.html