# It is possible to record sound with HTML5 and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I wonder if it is possible to record and play sounds with HTML5. In that way it will work in all main plataforms, like mobiles and pc's.

I found this old post [Is it possible to record sound with HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996377/is-it-possible-to-record-sound-with-html5) but maybe now it is posible.

Comment: I *think* the recording part is still in the works. Playing, on the other hand, is easy.

Comment: After some more reading, it is available on a couple mobile browsers, but that's about it. Read [this](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/)

Comment: Oh, and to clarify, its technically been *possible* for a while now. `navigator.getUserMedia()` is the API. It's browser support that's the issue.